# TypeError: require(...).listen is not a function ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to execute a .js file and is giving me the following error

[image: error]

The piece of code that is apparently giving me problems is

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
```

Can someone tell what the problem is? I have very little experience with Javascript and Node.js :/

Comment: Have you installed `socket.io`? `npm install socket.io` from https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Comment: please post the error message as text rather than as image/screenshots

Answer (score 1):

This whole thing is a bit confusing because socket.io supports all sorts of ways of initializing it and there are variations depending upon whether you want to hook up to an existing http(s) server or have it create its own server.

If you just want a socket.io server by itself, you would do this:

```
const io = require('socket.io')();
```

This uses the socket.io `Server` factory function and passes it default options (which assumes port 80).

---

If you want an http server that you can both use with Express and with socket.io, you would do this:

```
// create http server and start it
const app = require('express')();
const server = app.listen();

// create socket.io server and bind it to an existing http server
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Or this:

```
// create Express listener instance
const app = require('express')();

// create http server and bind the Express listener instance to it
const server = http.createServer(app);

// create socket.io server and bind it to the existing http server
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

// start the http server
server.listen();
```

Both of these use the socket.io `Server` factory function and pass it an existing http server object that it will share and hook up to.

Or (this syntax not used very often), if you want to more deliberately create a stand-alone socket.io server instance yourself:

```
// Load socket.io Server class from socket.io module
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

// create socket.io server instance
const io = new Server();

// start socket.io server
io.listen();
```

---

Your code is not working for a couple reasons:

1. `require('socket.io')` returns a `Server` factory function that doesn't have a `.listen()` method.  You need a server instance to get a `.listen()` method.
2. You don't pass `app` to a socket.io instance.  You pass `app` to an http server instance when you create that server with `http.createServer()` or you hook them together automatically with `app.listen()` which creates the http server for you in that `.listen()` method.

FYI, the socket.io `.listen()` method on a socket.io `Server` instance can either accept a port number (which defaults to 80 if not passed) or it can accept an existing, already created http server instance.  The `Server` class factory function which is what `require('socket.io')` returns will also accept those two types of arguments as illustrated above.

---

FYI, I assumed you're using Express because of your use of the `app` variable.  If that's not the case, then please show the rest of the code that shows what `app` is and where it comes from.